# Setting image using Imagepath does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, imageview

Trying to set images to image view using the image paths.

My image path

```
   String img_path ="/storage/sdcard0/Fbt/xylo.jpg";
```

image path code

```
              private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}

    selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
           String path= imageFile.toString();
```

output =/storage/sdcard0/Fbt/xylo.jpg

I tried all possible code still there is no success

1. ```
    ImageView carpict =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
    carpict.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   ```

2.

```
       Uri image22 =(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+img_path));


       InputStream imageStream = null;

            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(image22);

                Bitmap carpic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);


               // carpic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(carpic, 72,72, false); 
                carpict.setImageBitmap(carpic);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

3rd.

```
          carpict.setImageURI
            (Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+img_path));
```

4th.

```
   File imgFile =new File("img_path");
 carpict.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

I have also added

```
     <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: what error you got ? post logcat..

Comment: 4th posibility is wrong here...remove double quote ..

Comment: @MukeshKumar there is no error the imageview is not set. its blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the image itself when i tried with other images it worked  images with formats **.jpg .png  .jpeg**

```
     ImageView carpict =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
     carpict.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Here is the image xylo.jpg which is not getting set, don't know why

http://www.mediafire.com/?lh75aco1en8f3ot

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        System.out.println("sdcard path:"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/images.png");
        imageView.setBackground(d);
```

Comment: tried this too no error! but the image view is blank and the src set in xml disappears and sets to blank

Comment: there is no error in logcat ! file path is correct i got it using private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
return contentURI.getPath();
} else {
cursor.moveToFirst();
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
return cursor.getString(idx);
}
}

File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
String path= imageFile.toString();
i got the image path as /storage/sdcard0/Fbt/xylo.jpg

Comment: Also tried changing  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA with MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA  still i got /storage/sdcard0/Fbt/xylo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("PathToFile"));
```

or if you have the file reference:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                      +"/Fleet/xylo.jpg");
```

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file));
```

This should work. You will need to use the file constructor version of Uri.parse to correctly set the image.

Do check if the image is present in this location, or if the image is valid. And please post the logs if this also doesn't work.

Comment: getting this error The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Comment: You need to get the file path string,and not the file object. Or, if you have the file, you could directly use that.

Comment: @ Kumar Bibek  treid this is this correct?               File imgFile =new File("/storage/sdcard0/Fleet/xylo.jpg");
         carpict.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File(imgFile)));

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to File at File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                      +"/Fleet/xylo.jpg");

Comment: imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file)); cant be used so im using imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));

Comment: log cat doesnt have any images

Answer (score 0):

Stirng path="///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.package.name/files/Download/Images/one-3.jpg"; //chang with your image file path

File file  = new File(path);

imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getPath()));

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.